# Make API call based on route parameter in Nuxt 3 dynamic compopnent

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, watch, nuxtjs3

I'm attempting to create a simple Nuxt 3 app for learning purposes that uses [dynamic routes](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes) to load data from an API when the page is loaded. What I'm trying to figure out is how to use the route `id` param with the  composition API to call an external API and make the data available in the component.

So here is my basic folder structure:

```
/pages
   \
   index.vue
   /currency
        \
        [id].vue
```

index.vue:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>

    <table border="1 px solid">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Details</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="currency in data.data" :key="data.id">
        <td>{{ currency.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ currency.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ currency.price_usd }}</td>
        <td>
          <NuxtLink :to="'/currency/' + currency.id">{{ currency.id }}</NuxtLink>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    const {data} = await useFetch('/api/coinlore/tickers');

    return {
      data
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is what I have for `[id].vue`

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>{{ data.data.name }} Detail page</h1>
    {{ $route.params.id }}
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    const {data} = await useFetch('/api/coinlore/ticker?id=90');

    console.log(data);

    return {
      data
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Going from this [blog post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/watch-vue-route-params-query-with-composition-api-97b3c8c402e) I tried this

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>{{ data.name }} Detail page</h1>
    {{ $route.params.id }}
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    const coin = reactive({});
    function fetchCoin(id) {
       const {data} = await useFetch('/api/coinlore/ticker?id=' + $route.params.id);
       coin = data;
    }

    watch('$route.params.id', fetchCoin)

    return {
      coin
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

but no dice there, either.

How can I simply 1) make my API call and 2) populate the data by using the `id` param in my `[id].vue` component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`useRoute()` hook](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute):

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {          
    const route = useRoute();                                       
    const { data: coin } = await useFetch('/api/coinlore/ticker?id=' + route.params.id);

    return { coin }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-3-usefetch-from-route-params-golsx4?file=/pages/currency/%5Bid%5D.vue)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically pass the id in route params like:

```html
<NuxtLink :to="{path: '/currency', params : {id: currency.id} }">{{ currency.id }}</NuxtLink>
```

This piece of code will redirect to /currency/id

Also, the folder structure should be like:

```
/pages  
  /currency  
    [id].vue
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help :_)

In index.vue it's better to use programatic routing:

```js
<NuxtLink :to="{path: '/currency', params : {id: currency.id} }">{{ currency.id }}</NuxtLink>
// it will build link: `/currency/[id]`
```

and as posted by Tony19 there's a need to define **route** (useRoute hook) in the component:

```js
// import in script
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

// define route from 'vue'
const route = useRoute()
    
// read ID from route params
const currencyId = route.params.id
    
// actually it's better use literal string for using dynamic data => better reading
const { data: coin } = await useFetch(`/api/coinlore/ticker?id=${currencyId}`);
```