# Unable to assign returned API data to variable in Nuxt 3 setup function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, destructuring, nuxtjs3

I'm working (still) on a Nuxt 3 demo that's pretty straightforward, and for some reason I'm banging my head against something that should be simple.

All I'm doing is attempting to get data for a particular cryptocurrency from the [Coinlore API](https://www.coinlore.com/cryptocurrency-data-api) and display it in a table (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71317779/make-api-call-based-on-route-parameter-in-nuxt-3-dynamic-compopnent/71370461#71370461) for more detail). The return value from the API is like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "90",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "nameid": "bitcoin",
      "rank": 1,
      "price_usd": "20492.28",
      "percent_change_24h": "1.44",
      "percent_change_1h": "-0.14",
      "percent_change_7d": "0.34",
      "market_cap_usd": "390736994700.36",
      "volume24": "22963499957.29",
      "volume24_native": "1120592.68",
      "csupply": "19067521.00",
      "price_btc": "1.00",
      "tsupply": "19067521",
      "msupply": "21000000"
    }
  ],
  "pending": false,
  "error": null
}
```

so what I want to do is just get the first (and only) array item from the `data` object and make it available in the template. What I initially had was this:

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const { data: coin }  = await useFetch('/api/ticker?id=' + route.params.id)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ coin[0].name }} Detail page</h2>
    <table border="1 px solid">
      <thead>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Price - US $</th>
        <th>Market Cap - US $</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ coin[0].symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin[0].rank }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin[0].price_usd }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin[0].market_cap_usd }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

but that's ugly having to use array notation for a single item in the template.

As I understand per the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-bindings-are-exposed-to-template), top level variables in the `setup` function should be made available in the template, but when I try this

```
<script setup>
  const route = useRoute()
  const { data }  = await useFetch('/api/ticker?id=' + route.params.id)
  const coin = data[0];
</setup>

<template>
  <h2>{{ coin.name }} Detail page</h2>

...
</template>
```

I get an error message that says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`.

so for some reason my 'coin' variables value isn't being assigned the value from `data[0]`.

In the Vue dev tools inspector, it looks like this:

[image]

If I try this:

```
let coin = ref(data[0]);
```

I still get the undefined error.

This is really basic stuff that I do all the time, so it seems related to the Composition API. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How about checking with data.value? I read in an answer that With a `ref` you need to use `value` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is the entire response object you get from the fetch request. Inside that, there is an array called `data` too, so that can create a little bit of confusion.
If I replicate your code in a simple project, I can get the first object in the array like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ crypto }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    const { data: crypto } = await useAsyncData("crypto", async () => {
        const { data } = await useFetch("/api/crypto");
        return data.value.data;
    }, {
        transform: (data: any) => {
            return data.data[0]; // this returns the BTC object, nothing else
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access your variable you should do

```
const { data: coin }  = await useFetch('/api/ticker?id=' + route.params.id)
```

then you can refer to the coin with

```
let mycoin = coin.value.data[0]; //Notice the value attribute!
```

In my case

```
const { data: bici } = await useFetch(`${config.public.apiBase}/bici/sales.json`,  {pick: ["biciUsate", "biciNuove"]} );
let biciUsate = bici.value.biciUsate;
```

Comment: `//Notice the value attribute!` it's what saved me. Thanks!